# Build APK from existing Ionic 1 Android Project

Tags: android, ionic-framework

An Android project is given to me by a client which I assume is done in ionic v1. I am asked to generate an APK file and build the code. I followed the steps given in [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html) to set up my system to build an ionic app but I am unable to build the project. I am getting the following message:

[image]
Here is a screenshot of the project structure. The client does not seem to have access to the original developer any longer. I am completely new to ionic. One of my colleagues guessed that it could be an ionic v1 project. If anyone knows what it could be then please help me build the APK.

[image]

**Edit**
As suggested by @PareshGami I tried to create new project and copy pasted `ionic.config.json` to the exixting project. No getting following error:

`There was an error serving your Ionic application: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\utils\npmScripts.js:61:32
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)`

Comment: that project was build on ionic-v3+ version

Comment: Thanks, @PareshGami for the quick reply. Why do I get `cordova is not a valid task` error? Am I doing anything wrong? Isn't the command `ionic cordova build android` correct?

Comment: There are lots of setup config in local system you need to do before apk generation process

Comment: I have followed the steps give [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html). I have also set environment variables and all.

Comment: When I do `ionic serve` I get `Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?`

Comment: that means you are not inside of project folder

Comment: I am in the same directory as in the screenshot. Still, I get `Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?`

Comment: Create new ionic 3 project and you can find this file in newly created project so you can just copy paste in your project might be that will help

Comment: @PareshGami Please check the edits. I am getting different error now.

Comment: Remove node_module and npm install again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174153/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-arti).